# PHP - Get array values

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to access the values of *token* and *token secret* via PHP in this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [consumer_secret] => HrsfBFrXoMBDP8MyB
            [signature_methods] => Array
                (
                    [0] => HMAC-SHA1
                )

          [token_type] => access
            [token] => x0CHWGnPIxDDTIQU
            [token_secret] => 7zVJkIwlwgJY1HeVQX
        )

    [1] => RIrF7eCVhrQ
)
```

I tried `$_SESSION[0]->token;` but there is no value in it.
How to get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array.

`echo $_SESSION[0]['token']; // Echos 'x0CHWGnPIxDDTIQU'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
$_SESSION[0]['token']
```

Comment: I don't get it. If use this `print_r (array_values($_SESSION));` the values are there but I can access them through `echo $_SESSION[0]['token'];` Any ideas?

Comment: OK, for some reason this works `$_SESSION = array_shift($_SESSION);
echo $_SESSION['token'];` but this not `echo $_SESSION['token'];`. Does anybody have an idea why is that?